# How to switch DLC in Tropico 4

Tags: tropico-4

I have just bought a couple of extensions for Tropico 4, but I don't understand how to switch from one to another. It seems I am stuck in *Modern times*. How can start Tropico 4 with *El Plantador* instead?

Answer (score 8):

#### El Plantador is always enabled

*El Plantador* is a very small DLC; it only adds a new building, a new avatar, a few decorations, and a new mission (which is separate from the main campaign and the Modern Times campaign). The building, avatar, and decorations are available in *all* games, whether they're Modern Times or not. It should already be enabled if you've bought it; if you can build a Plantation (in the Food/Resources section), then it's enabled.

I've bought both *Modern Times* and *El Plantador*, and I'm currently playing the Modern Times campaign while building Plantations, so the two DLCs work together just fine.

#### Turning Modern Times on and off: only in sandbox games.

The *Modern Times DLC* adds two things:

1. A complete *Modern Times* campaign, 12 missions long, that is entirely separate from the regular campaign. Of course, the *Modern Times* timeline and buildings are always enabled for these scenarios.
2. The ability to enable the *Modern Times* timeline in sandbox games, and to build scenarios that use *Modern Times*. Various technologies are unlocked at particular points in time, but sandbox games always start in 1950, so you won't be unable to unlock a few of the last items on the timeline. (The timeline events - like *La Violencia!* - will be randomized, but the building unlocks are pretty consistent.)

**If you don't like *Modern Times*, you can turn it off in sandbox games.  For scenarios, you're stuck with whatever the scenario creator chose. If you don't want to play with *Modern Times*, play scenarios that don't use it.**

The "Challenges" (scenarios created by random internet people) are broken into two groups: *Modern Times* and Not-Modern-Times. There's a selector at the top of the screen when you're looking at the challenges.

Almost all of the scenarios under "Extra Missions" are non-*Modern-Times*.

(There are a couple of minor bugs when playing non-*Modern-Times* games, mostly around random reputation-raising missions from some character that request a *Modern Times* building or edict, like the Telecom building.  Just dismiss those missions instead of accepting them; you can't fulfill them. This might be fixed by now.)

Comment: My character was "el plantador", I suppose it was not there before! I thought this DLC would be bigger, but yes, the description on steam reads exactly as you say. My question somewhat remains though on how to disable Modern times and go back to the traditional missions/scenario.

Comment: You should be able to select the regular campaign instead of the Modern Times campaign. For sandbox games, you can enable/disable Modern Times. (Haven't checked for other scenarios yet.)